# Cannot add GMapControl to Visual C# studio from GMap.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-maps-api-3, gmap.net

I need to add Google Maps in one of my projects and I found that I can use GMap.NET. Show I downloaded the GMap.NET and I add as references **GMap.NET.Core.dll**
and **GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll** as shown in the guide of the GMap.net. Show according to the guide in **"Choose Items"** in toolbox section it must has appeared the GMapControl item but it hasn't. I haven't find any solution to this problem so I decided to make this article. Sorry for my bad english, I would be glad if anyone can help.

Comment: try to add new tab, and then click choose items and select GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll

Answer (score 0):

Go to TOOLS menu then click on "choose toolbox items...". Select .NET Framework Components, then click browse.Add GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll there. Then when you open your toolbox, you should see GMapControl on General menu. If it's not there, check other toolbox menus.